# Search google places containing '-' character

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Greetings and thanks for the read/help in advance!

Trying to do a Google places search for criteria that contain the '-'  example 't-mobile'

If I send the following request

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=39.19148364879271,-75.54520000000002&name="t-mobile"&radius=24140.16&sensor=false&key=myPrivateKey`

I get no results

Changing the request to

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=39.19148364879271,-75.54520000000002&name="t mobile"&radius=24140.16&sensor=false&key=myPrivateKey`

Returns multiple 'T-Mobile' records.  URLEncoding has no effect on the '-' character.  Could just remove any instances of the '-' in the search criteria but that doesn't feel correct.   What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: You should report it

Comment: Report it here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:PlacesAPI%20type:Defect